# Docker Compose Cant Find Entrypoint on Windows Machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file that was created by our team for easy container deployment on local machines but I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work.

I am attempting to run this on Windows 10 Professional. My source files are located in the D drive where I have created /var/www/html/ directory structure. OS is on the C drive. Docker has access to both C and D drives.

Ultimately I always get an error that says:

`ERROR: for test_container  Cannot start service test_container: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./Scripts/docker_compose_init.sh\": stat ./Scripts/docker_compose_init.sh: no such file or directory": unknown`

So I believe the problem to be in the entrypoint, but I have tried so many different ways to spell out the path and I never can get the container to start.

I've tried:

1. Using full absolute path
2. preceding with /bin/bash/
3. preceding with sh
4. various paths with single slashes, double slashes, anything I could think of really

I also realize the windows line endings could be an issue, but I have confirmed many times that my line endings are unix.

Below is a greatly simplified version of the compose file after narrowing it down to what was directly causing the problem.

```
                    image: "a useful php image"
                    volumes:
                        - /var/www/html
                    tty: true
                    working_dir: /var/www/html
                    entrypoint: ./Scripts/docker_compose_init.sh
```

How do I get it to properly start the container and find the docker_compose_init.sh file?

Comment: Is `docker_compose_init.sh` inside `/var/www/html/Scripts` directory? And is `/var/www/html/Scripts` directory part of `PATH`?

Comment: ```docker_compose_init.sh``` is inside ```/var/www/html/site_source/Scripts```. I have tried making the complete path to the scripts folder as the entrypoint - but the pertinent directory has never been part of PATH.

Comment: Okay and do I need to add anything to my PATH environment variables? The above alone did not work and produced the same error.

Comment: So, if you use absolute path you still get `no such file or directory`? Also, can you confirm that the file exists in container?

Comment: That is correct, I still get ```no such file or directory": unknown```. Because the container doesn't successfully start, I am unable to navigate within it. I can confirm the file does indeed exist in my normal file system.

Comment: Well, in that case we need to have [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's not much we can do with information provided. We don't know if you're using an existing image or building your on from Dockerfile. A lot of information is missing.